# Are you as distracted as me by the new top bar?

Tags: discussion, design

Contrast on steroids, mostly due to the grey page background at this stack.

The top bar icons really **SCREAM** at me now and are nothing but a distraction.... it's all I see on every page.. yanking my eye to the top right corner....

I'm merely curious if anyone else is bothered by them as much as I am.

Related Meta post of mine: [Can I dim the top bar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377607/can-i-dim-the-top-bar)

Comment: Agreed. Also the new message notification sign is too small but too contrasty

Comment: Pff, I have so much custom CSS for this site already. A few extra lines are no bother 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thankfully**.. the icons appear to have been ever-so-slightly tweaked in color overnight.

The change appears to be made to the theme specifically related to *this* stack. It's so slight that the change almost goes unnoticed.. but, the "neon" aspect of the icons has been diminished *considerably*.

[image]

(No idea if the number bubbles are better... I haven't seen those here yet (no notifications for me).